# Apple Photos App Stuck For Days "Closing the library..."

Tags: photos, photos.app

I recently migrated my library from iPhoto to the Apple Photos app. There's probably around 13,000 photos/videos in the library. After migrating the library, I closed Photos, and it is now been stuck "Closing the library..." for two days.

I checked the activity monitor shortly after it appeared to be stuck and there were seemingly related processes consuming high amounts of CPU resources, such as `com.apple.photos.VideoConversionService` and `photoanalysisd`. So I waited, assuming those processes are preventing the app exit and just need to finish what they are working on.

It is now day 2 and I still see Photos is "Closing the library..." and the processes are still live, but aren't consuming any CPU any longer.

Other forums/sites talk about the "Closing the library..." issue and suggest just force quitting Photos. However, I don't want to do this if there any risk on corrupting the library, or killing a process that needs to complete to make the library complete.

Any suggestions on what I should do next?

Comment: It's been a couple of months now.  Are you still waiting?  Did you follow the suggestion to forcibly quit Photos?

Comment: I ended up force closing the library and starting computer. Hard to tell what damage (if any) was done.

Comment: Yes, I wonder if there is a way to do some kind of integrity check on the library.  Have you had the same thing happen again since October?